# How to use the getter from MainWindow C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, getter

My problem is, that I can't use my getter in my other class because the getter is in the MainWindow.xaml.cs class.

When I use this Code* in my other class ControlKey.cs I get an exception that the Application is hold on. I think it want's to create an other Window but I just want to use the getter in the class ControlKey.cs

*MainWindow.xaml.cs* Class:

```
 public bool GetPresentationStarted(){
            return presentationsarted;
 }
```

---

*

*ControlKey.cs* Class:

**`MainWindow mWindow = new MainWindow();`**

```
bool presentationStarted;
```

And later I have an if statement where I do something if presentationStarted is true.
...

```
presentationStarted = mWindow.GetPresentationStarted();
```

...

```
if (presentationStarted == true) {
...
}
```

I don't know how to do it different. I hope someone can help me

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Views should not know about this kind of stuff, look into use MVVM

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you meant :/

Comment: Oh that means I cant use: MainWindow mWindow = new MainWindow(); I would not get the value of presentationStarted from MainWindow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But how can I use the getter in my other class? I need a reference to the methods of the MainWindow class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each instance of MainWindow has its own copy of `presentationsarted`. If you want the value of `presentationsarted` from the main window of your application, you can't just create a new instance of MainWindow. That new instance has nothing to do with the other instance that's already showing.

But you can get the actual main window itself.

```
var mWindow = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;

var x = mWindow.GetPresentationStarted();
```

That'll work, but it's not the best way to write a WPF application. You should really learn the MVVM ("Model-View-ViewModel") pattern. Then each window would have its own viewmodel that owns properties like that one, and all the viewmodels can share a reference to some common viewmodel that has state everybody cares about. WPF with the MVVM pattern is immensely powerful. The learning curve is rough, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out now! I know I have to improve my "skills" :/

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't require any other parameters from the MainWindow class just try to use:
1. Static property. For example, you can create

```
public static bool? MainWindow.PresentationStarted {get; private set;}
```

and set the value from any event you prefer.

Or

2.Create shared instance like:

```
public static bool? SharedClass.MainPresentationStarted {get; set;}.
```

So you have an access to the value:

```
if (MainWindow.PresentationStarted == true)
```